# Slow performance on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, laptop, dell-inspiron

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 5502, which has Intel i7 11th gen and a Nvidia GPU.

I have used both Ubuntu and Windows 10 as the operating system (OS) and experience the huge different in performance.

**Note**: I use only one OS at a time, not dual boot.

The issue is caused by the heavily GPU-use application, which is a game name [Dota 2](https://www.dota2.com/home) in this case. The game is playable on both OSes.

### On Ubuntu

On Ubuntu, the game is so smooth without any lagging during a 60-minute game. The fan is quiet unless you let the laptop touch your ear.

However, the game UI is just acceptable. It does not have any fancy animation, but only the necessary one. It's like the game is in the lowest settings.

### On Windows

On Windows, the game starts as smooth as on Ubuntu. There are fancy animations, which is awesome to see.

However, the noise of the fan can be heard as soon as the game is opened. It is so loud that you could hear it while standing a meter away from the laptop.

Afraid of blowing up my laptop, I change the settings for performance and goodbye beauty. Even doing that, the fan is still so loud.

After 15 minutes in-game, it starts lagging. The performance is so low that the character jumps from time to time instead of walking. The laptop is warm, not hot.

### Any solution?

The environment for the test is:

- Ubuntu: Wayland with default settings.
- Windows 10: Power Mode is set to Optimized. Set it to Ultra Performance makes the laptop hot like lava and makes it worse.

Do you know what causes this issue? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you got enough memory (say 16GB) .  And are your drive(s) all fast NVMe drives

Comment: How much memory does this machine have? And what kind of drive? It may not have been specified for gaming

Comment: @John I have 16GB RAM (2 8GBs), using SSD drive. Dell Inspiron is not specified for gaming, but it is just an example of a heavy application. While Ubuntu doing great, Windows doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the problem is using the game on Windows with high
performance settings while controlling the temperatures.

The first step is to check what happens when the fans start blowing hard.
Use the Task Manager, Performance section, to see whether the GPU or the
CPU are being used.

For monitoring the CPU and GPU temperatures, you could use
[Open Hardware Monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/).

Once you find where is the heat is coming from, you may attack the causes.
For example:

- If CPU is used excessively, find why the game doesn't use the GPU
- If GPU is used excessively, perhaps you're missing some graphical codecs
- etc.

Comment: The GPU usage is 70% - 100% and it is over 55oC. It can disable network connection after the long time use.

Comment: For a CPU, 55 degrees is normal - you should get worried only if it exceeds 90 degrees. The reason for heating might be blocked airways, so cleaning them might help. Also interior dust can cause heating (to be cleaned up VERY carefully).

Comment: I put my laptop on a stand when I use it. I don't think it is a blocked airways problem because this only happens on Windows, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Some laptops are conceived with insufficient airways. The drivers of Windows and Linux exercise the hardware very differently, so heat generation might also differ. In your place, I would clean up everything I can. If this does not solve the problem, you may either ask a repair-shop, or as last resort accept that your laptop is a hot one and take steps to avoid over-heating.

Comment: I have asked Dell for support, and they told me that my laptop is designed to do the light work like writing document, browsing the web. The heavy work like gaming, video editing is not supported. In other words, this is not a bug, but a feature :)

Comment: There are methods for cooling a laptop, such as coolpads, elevating the back edge a bit for air circulation beneath, etc. I don't know if better fans or cooling systems exist for a laptop and for your model. You may also lower maximum CPU from 100% to 95%, and this will also have an effect on the heat and not so much on performance.